# Using Pageable to query a collection

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities. A `NewsCategory` and a `NewsItem` which have a one-to-many relationship.

#### NewsCategory

```
@Entity
public class NewsCategory extends AbstractEntity<Long> {
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<NewsItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<NewsItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

#### NewsItem

```
@Entity
public class NewsItem extends AbstractEntity<Long> {
    private String title;
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;

    private String resource;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private String content;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

#### Repository interface

I would like to have the `items` collection to be pageable but I'm having some difficulties with defining the repository interface for it.

*This interface does not work like expected.*

```
public interface NewsCategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<NewsCategory, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT e.items FROM #{#entityName} e WHERE e = ?1")
    public List<NewsItem> findItems(NewsCategory category, Pageable pageable);
}
```

When executing `findItems()` the following exception is thrown.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [newscatego0_.id.items] with element property reference [startDate] [SELECT e.items FROM NewsCategory e WHERE e = ?1 order by e.items.startDate asc]
```

How can I modify the above interface so it will return a portion of the `items` property using Spring Data and `Pageable`?

Comment: May I ask why you want to execute a query for the `NewsItem`s of a `NewsCategory` if you already have the category at hand and would only need to call `getItems()` on it? It's also bad practice to create relationships pointing to potentially unbounded collections. I'd recommend to let the `NewsItem` point to a category and have a dedicated `NewsItemRepository` if you want page-by-page access to the items.

Comment: Thanks @OliverGierke. That is exactly what I end up doing :-)